# Android app to track occurrences of multiple events

Tags: android, productivity

Can anyone recommend an Android app that will track occurrences of multiple events?

For example, let's say you want to count birds.  You would then enter 'eagle', blue jay', and 'sparrow'.  Each time you see one of those birds, you would click a '+1' button.  The software would log each occurrence and present a summary of the information in both a numeric and graph form.

Ideally, it could export the data to a CSV file or a similar data format, although this is not a requirement.

The ability to track multiple different types of events is a requirement.

This app could be used for a variety of applications.  For example, you could use it to track how many glasses of water you drink every day, how many times you exercise per day, or how many times you complete any task.

Preferably, the app will be free-of-charge (gratis), but that is not a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

If you [search for "tally counter" in the Google app store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=tally%20counter) multiple alternatives appears, and if not gratis (with ads of course) reasonably priced pro version exists.

For your particular case of counting multiple thingies at once I think two stood out of the crowd: [Advanced tally counter pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yingwen.counterpro) and [T-Counter Pro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TCounter.pro). They both have an option to display lists of named counters, whilst maintaining the option to count up and down easily.

At least the former could also change the increment, which could be useful if tallying something like drinking water where you could change the increment to how many units of water are in each container (i.e 2 dl in each glass).

**Edit:** Reread your question and noted the part on graphing, which could rule out the previous two, but could lift the app [KeepScore - Score Keeper](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.nolanlawson.keepscore) a little higher.  It displays and has some different options running it towards keeping game scored, but could be an answer to your needs.